# Excel VBA Workbook_Open Application or Object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that will run a macro once opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    GetPaymentTypes
    CreateHyperlinks paymentType, paymentTypeLocation

End Sub
```

Both the subs `GetPaymentTypes` and `CreateHyperLinks` run fine by themselves (they are in a module of their own) but I get the Application Defined or Object Defined error when Workbook_Open runs.

The error occurs in `CreateHyperlinks`:

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks(paymentType, paymentTypeLocation)

    ' Below errors with Worksheets(1) or Active Sheet, ONLY from Workbook_Open()
    With ActiveSheet
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(paymentTypeLocation), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="", _
            ScreenTip:="Go to 80 byte population guide for: " & paymentType, _
            TextToDisplay:=paymentType
    End With
End Sub
```

I must be referencing the 'ActiveSheet' for the hyperlinks wrong, but I cannot seem to solve this. Many thanks for any assistance received.

The variable paymentType is defined in the class module. Private paymentType As String

There is a function that populates an array of paymentTypes. I then assign the relevant one to paymentType and call CreateHyperlinks passing the paymentType to it.

Comment: I don't see where the variable *paymentTypeLocation* as been assigned a value.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I feel I've gone very wrong here perhaps, paymentType is a class varible that is assigned elsewhere and that value is passed to this sub. There is a Function GetPaymentTypes that populates an array of types, sets a single string to 'paymentType' then calls CreateHyperlinks passing that string.

Comment: To assist our debug, place a **MsgBox** within each Sub to verify the inputs.

Comment: It maybe a case that your variables are not passed. Try to set them as public.

Comment: @lowak It was indeed the private variables. Is there a VBA equivalent to a Getter method in VBA? Is public variables OK in this case (no details being used are private, or sensitive or customer facing)? Many thanks to both of you, that was a bit blindingly obvious (though I would not have seen it). If you want to post an answer I'll happily accept and upvote. Also I think this being a 'module' after all and not a 'class module' is causing me confusion and some issues here also. I'm not a programmer, but my usual was Java with Private variables then a setX and getX method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as we agreed in comments it is about your variables are not passed to `Workbook_open`.

Remedy for your problem is to set your variables as Public.

Example: `Public paymentType as String`

Actually there is nothing wrong about making them `Public`. Variable having Public property is set and all subroutines can use them (not only the one that sets it).

Sometimes you need to set them public if you are writing more complicated subroutine. Anyway, if you are sensitive to data privacy you should not use Excel files as your data carriers.

A little guide to variable scope: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a VBA equivalent to a Getter method in VBA?"

Yes there is, here is an example

```
Private mSomeValue As String

Public Property Get SomeValue() As String
    SomeValue= mSomeValue    
End Property

'A corresponding setter method could look like this'

Public Property Let SomeValue(aValue As String)
    mSomeValue = aValue
End Property
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks for answering that. It seems so clear now that you have written it! I'll give the 'accepted answer' to lowak as they answered the direct question. But definitely a +1 for this as it is very very useful.